# Add custom fields to Maximo Result Set

Tags: resultset, maximo

I'm using Maximo 7.5 and I added few columns to an custom table. How to get those columns in Startcenter result set. The new fields are visible in Workorder application

Comment: It is better to include a visual/textual example in your question to get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on an older fix pack, you'll need to insert a row into RESULTSETCOLS, as demonstrated by the insert statement below which was excerpted from [this Technote](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21409330). Note that you will need to adjust the values for the first three columns to suit your needs.

```
insert into resultsetcols
( app, attribute, maintable, resultsetcolsid ,rowstamp)
values
('WOTRACK', 'LOCATION.DESCRIPTION', 'WORKORDER', resultsetcolsseq.nextval, maxseq.nextval);
```

However, if you're on Maximo 7.5.0.7+, you can use the front end to accomplish your goals. As detailed in [this Technote](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21980423) (which talks about 7.6 but also applies to 7.5.0.7+)...

1. Create an Object Structure based on the Main Table of the application the Result Set's Query is from. It is important to set Consumed By to `REPORTING` and include objects you want to show data from in your Result Set on the second or lower level.
2. Use the Set Report Object Structure Security option in the Report Administration application to grant yourself permission to use the Object Structure you just created.
3. Create/edit the Result Set and choose the fields you want to include. (Note: If the Result Set Setup screen lacks an Object List tree-control, you probably need to change the `webclient.resultset.relatedattributes` System Property to 1, as detailed in [this Technote](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21684399).)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please add context of your links in the answer, so when the links stop working we still have the option to understand your answer.

Comment: I saved the URLs mentioned into webarchive. So, if the link doesn't work, you can use the Wayback Machine to retrieve it.

Comment: The Object Structure picklist was hidden - we had to use the `Application Designer` to edit the `Result Set Setup` page, click on the hidden `Object Structure` box, and clear the "RELOBJSTR" `Signature Option` on the `Advanced` tab. Alternative you could configure the is signature option permission. [REF](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=f0cbd8e9-f311-4e53-85f0-0d87ca52a3d5)