# not getting custom field while editing resultset portlet in Start Center in Maximo

Tags: maximo

Why am I not getting my custom field while editing resultset portlet in Start Center in Maximo? I have manually added it to `RESULTSETCOLS` column.

We can relate this issue with the below-asked question.

[Add custom fields to Maximo Result Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632881/add-custom-fields-to-maximo-result-set)

I have added a new system property `webclient.resultset.relatedattributes` with a value equal to `1`. Yet, the custom field  I have added is not visible.

I should be able to add the custom field based on the relationship of application in resultset portlet of Maximo start center.

Comment: Ask your question in the body (not in the title part)

Comment: What version of Maximo are you on?

Comment: How to troubleshoot your problem is really difficult without knowing your version, since the functionality in the subject area changed drastically in 7.6. Before that, you inserted rows into `RESULTSETCOLS` with SQL; after that, you make a Report Object Structure and then configure everything in the UI. So, without knowing your version, we can't help you. It would also help to know which app the result set's query is against.

Comment: Maximo version 7.6.1
I am facing this issue for any app of Maximo like WO, SR, PM, etc. in a resultset .